# Get closed form of a series from its generating function

Tags: generating-functions

If we have the ordinary generating function of a series:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{e^z -3}$

Can we get its closed form?

Comment: What you have is already a closed form for the generating function. Did you mean a closed form for the coefficients? (Also, I think you meant to have the same variable on both sides.) (Also, what have you tried?)

Comment: As written, $f(0) = - 1/2$, which probably isn't right (most generating functions are for non-negative coefficients, even non-negative integers).

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients of many generating functions just don't have "simple" form, when they turn out often they get christened as special sequences:

- Bell numbers (total number of partitions of $n$ elements): $e^{e^z - 1}$
- Ordered Bell numbers (number of ordered partitions of $n$ elements, "competitions with ties"): $\frac{1}{2 - e^z}$
- Bernoulli numbers: $\frac{z e^z}{e^z - 1}$

This is just a list off the top of my head. You might get an expression for your sequence in terms of those "well known" sequences.

In any case, [OEIS](http://oeis.org) should be your first stop.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can find the terms of the sequence using the geometric series and the power series expansion of $e^x$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{e^x - 3} &= -\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{1 - e^x/3} = -\frac{1}{3} \sum_{n \geq 0} \left(\frac{e^x}{3}\right)^n = -\frac{1}{3} \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{3^{n}} e^{nx} = -\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(nx)^k}{k!}\\
&= -\frac{1}{3} \sum_{k \geq 0} \left(\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{n^k}{3^{n}}\right) \frac{1}{k!} x^k \, .
\end{align*}
We simplify the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} n^k x^n$ by repeatedly differentiating the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and multiplying by $x$.  That is,
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} n^k x^n = \left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right)^k \frac{1}{1-x} \, .
$$
(There may be a simpler expression for this, but I'm not aware of one.)  By setting $x = 1/3$, we obtain the sum in parentheses above.  Thus the $k^\text{th}$ term of your sequence will be the coefficient of $x^k$, which is
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{3} \sum_{k \geq 0} \left(\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{n^k}{3^{n}}\right) \frac{1}{k!} &= -\frac{1}{3} \sum_{k \geq 0} \left[\left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right)^k \frac{1}{1-x}\right]_{x = 1/3} \frac{1}{k!} \, .
\end{align*}
I guess this is a closed-ish form.